# Is there a way to test clicking on the passed PaperComponent of a material-ui Autocomplete component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-testing-library

I am rendering a material-ui Autocomplete with a custom PaperComponent, which adds a clickable footer. Looks like this:

[image]

It looks like neither the PaperComponent or autocomplete options actually render to the dom. Using Jest and React Testing Library, is there a way to simulate clicking on the footer? I'd like to click where it says "Advanced Instructor Finder", however querying for the text or the icon returns nothing. Adding a data-test id does not work, seems like it isn't in the DOM to begin with.

Here is my code:

```html
const AutocompleteOptionsWrapper = (passedProps) => {
    const children = passedProps.children;
    return (
      <Paper {...passedProps}>
        {children}
        <div // click here
          style={{
            cursor: 'pointer',
          }}
          onClick={onClick}
          onMouseDown={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
          }}
        >
          <SearchIcon style={{ marginRight: 10 }} color="primary" />
          <Typography color="primary">
            <FormattedMessage {...messages.advancedSearch} />
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    );
  };
  
  const ParentComponent = () => {
    ...
    return (
      <Autocomplete
        options={options}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              'aria-label': `instructorDropdown-${index + 1}`,
            }}
          />
        )}
        ...otherProps
        PaperComponent={AutocompleteOptionsWrapper}
      />
    );
  };
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not on the DOM?

Comment: Querying the text "Advanced Instructor Search" returns null, and the text (along with all of the dropdown options) couldn't be found by inspecting the HTML in the browser. I think it involves the shadow DOM somehow, but am not savvy enough to have a deeper understanding.

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox link so I can look at it? Also, if you inspect the element on a browser, you should see the HTML element. So it's just a matter of finding it with the right query and should be smooth sailing from there on.